# How to rigorously state this?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

***updated: still not sure:***

I am wondering what I should do to rigorously state/prove the following:

```
n_k >= n
```

When dealing with a subsequence. Basically, I want to mathematically state that the increments of our subsequence are greater than or equal to our main sequence increments (which are by definition strictly increasing by 1 for every increment, whereas n_k could increment by 2 for example).

Using the hint given below, I've gotten this far:`

```
As n_1 >= 1, our first case is proven
Assume this holds for n_k >= k
Proof
n_k+1 > n_k >= k
```

Where would I go from here to finish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>**Hint**: The sequence $(n_k)_{k \geq 1}$ is strictly increasing and satisfies $n_1 \geq 1$. Apply induction.</s>

**Update**: I originally misread your question. I thought you wanted to prove $n_k \geq k$ for all $k$. Rereading more carefully, it seems to me that what you want to prove is $n_{k+1}-n_k \geq 1$. But this is trivially true due to the fact that $(n_k)_k$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: Hey, I think I understand your hint, could you potentially read the OP and tell me if I'm going in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could comment on stuff instead of making new answers.

So following parsiad's hint and your edit+comment, you're just one step away from concluding your induction.

**Hint**: You have $n_{k+1} > k$, but remember that you're dealing with integers here...

Edit: Also since you took the trouble to edit your post, it would have been good to clarify the doubts expressed by parsiad?